# Непонятная подмена ссылок

Tags: браузер, dle

Пытаюсь настроить работу зеркала сайта. Есть основной домен domain.ru.
Создаю зеркало по адресу domain.su (или domain.pro). На зеркалах лежит полная копия основного сайта, без каких-либо изменений. На основном домене имеются ссылка вида sub.domain.ru/path/to/file. Проблема заключается в следующем: на зеркале все ссылки вида sub.domain.**ru**/path/to/file автоматически меняются на sub.domain.**su**/path/to/file, что не желательно.

Адрес данных ссылок прописан абсолютный. При этом если указать просто domain.ru, то подмены не происходит. Также заметил, что подмена есть только при указании ссылок в шаблонах. Смотрел работу шаблонизатора, но не нашел там ничего похожего на подмену ссылок.

Надеюсь что у кого-нибудь была похожаю проблема.

Движок dle 10.1.

Comment: и в чес вопрос? что значит подмена? - редирект?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как избавиться от этой подмены.

Comment: А подмена значит, что на странице вместо тех ссылок которые я пишу, выводяться другие.